# Extract the the row with match from the list

Tags: python, excel, pandas

- I have excel below

```
id,name,country
1,abc,Austria
2,cde,UK
3,efg,Germany
4,abc,US
```

- List is below
  `['UK','France','Poland','Sweden', 'US']`

How to extract the row if `df['country]` matches with list

Expected out is

```
2,cde,UK
4,abc,US
```

Its not wise to one bey one `df[df['country'].str.contains("UK")]`

Comment: df[df['country'].isin(['UK','France','Poland','Sweden', 'US])]

Comment: you don't need `str.contains()` because the country names are straight forward

Comment: make function which checks that is `df['Country']` value exist in your Country List